# Check if value is greater than zero in Java

Tags: java, boolean, byte

Let me start off my saying I'm an **absolute beginner in Java**, and what I've put together so far has taken me a loooong time.

So with that in mind, I have this snippet of my code which checks whether the user has entered a byte value, and shows an error message if they haven't:

```
while (!keyboard.hasNextByte()) {
     keyboard.next();
     System.err.print("Error, try again: ");
 }
```

What I'd like to add is one more condition which checks if the user has entered a value greater than zero. So something along these lines:

```
 while (!keyboard.hasNextByte() && keyboard > 0) {
```

How would I do that? I would also appreciate an explanation of the answer so I can learn more that way. Ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    byte savedInput;
    boolean savedHasNextByte;
    while (!(savedHasNextByte = keyboard.hasNextByte()) || (savedInput = keyboard.nextByte()) <= 0) {
        if (!savedHasNextByte) keyboard.next();
        System.err.print("Error, try again: ");
    }
```

Then get your value in `savedInput`.

**Explanation**

The `||` operator in Java is short-circuit. So:

If `!keyboard.hasNextByte()` (the input is not a byte) then the second part is not evaluated, it print the error, ignore the input, and get input again.

If `!keyboard.hasNextByte()` is false (the input is a byte) then you save the input `keyboard.nextByte()` into `savedInput` and check if it greater than 0.
If it isn't, then you ignore it too, otherwise you have your input in `savedInput` (not in `keyboard.nextByte()` since you have called it once already!)

However, if `||` is not short circuit, then `keyboard.nextByte()` is evaluated, regardless of `keyboard.hasNextByte()`, and that may cause error.

**Edit:** We have to save `hasNextByte()` because if `keyboard.hasNextByte()` then keyboard will be read by `keyboard.nextByte()`, and `hasNextByte()` would change!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answers and explanations, however when I try this code it doesn't work. It works for non-bytes, but not for negative numbers. I see what you're doing, and it makes sense to me, what doesn't make sense is why if a user enters a negative number they don't get an error the same way they do when they enter a non-byte.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work for -ve numbers. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Here's some info that might shed light on this mystery: when I write `System.out.println(savedInput);` after the `while` loop, and enter an acceptable value (e.g., 10), it's printed, which means the loop has ended. If I enter a non-byte value, I get an error message just as I should, which means the loop is still going. But when I enter a negative byte-number (e.g., -10), I don't get anything meaning the loop hasn't ended, but for some reason I also don't get the error message. Maybe that helps?

Comment: YES! Your last edit worked!!! Can you tell me what you changed and why please? (And THANK YOU!!!!)

Comment: I think the "Edit" part explained it. If `keyboard.hasNextByte()`, then `||` will evaluate the second part, thus possibly edit the value of `keyboard.hasNextByte()`, so you need to save it to `savedHasNextByte`. In the fourth line, only if the value has not been read then we read and ignore it by using `keyboard.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you really mean is while no valid byte **OR** equals to zero, ask user for input:

```
byte b;
while (!keyboard.hasNextByte() || (b=keyboard.nextByte()) <= 0) {
    System.err.print("Error, try again: ");
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate: I chose to use a byte to save memory because what I need this variable for later doesn't need to be a large number (hence up to 127 will do). But I also need it to be a positive number, so I need to restrict the range to 0 < keyboard =< 127